# Tailwind merge not able to combine color and typography classes

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I have defined a custom color `text-green`(colors) and a custom typography `text-card-highlight` (utilities) which has a font size and font weight. When using tailwind-merge, it is allowing only one out of these classes to get applied.

I am not able to understand why when no CSS attribute is common between the classes.

[image]

[image]

Everything works fine when I use the classes without tailwind-merge.

I have added the font classes to my tailwind config as utilities:

```
plugin(({ addUtilities, theme }) => {
    addUtilities(
        {
            '.text-card-subheading': {
                fontSize: theme('fontSize.xxs'),
                fontWeight: theme('fontWeight.normal'),
            },
            '@screen md': {
                '.text-card-subheading': {
                    fontSize: theme('fontSize.xs'),
                },
            },
        },
    )
})
```

Comment: `@media` has a higher preference over a simple class selector, that's why `font-size: 0.75rem;` is showing.

Comment: @MohammadMasoodAlam That's not my issue. When I am doing `className={twMerge("text-green text-card-highlight")}` only the text-card highlight gets applied and when I do `className={twMerge("text-card-highlight text-green")}` only the green color gets applied

Comment: Try to use comma between two classes, like this: `{twMerge('text-card-highlight', 'text-green')}`

Comment: @MohammadMasoodAlam tried everything but it is just overriding one for the other. When I view it in the browser devtools, I can see only one class getting applied.

Answer (score 4):

(I'm the author of tailwind-merge)

If you have a custom Tailwind CSS config, you need to configure tailwind-merge as well. You can read more about [tailwind-merge configuration](https://github.com/dcastil/tailwind-merge/blob/v1.12.0/docs/configuration.md) and there is also a [configuration recipe with an example](https://github.com/dcastil/tailwind-merge/blob/v1.12.0/docs/recipes.md#adding-custom-scale-from-tailwind-config-to-tailwind-merge-config) in the docs.

For your use case specifically:

The `text-green` class doesn't need to be configured in tailwind-merge and is supported right out of the box.

For `text-card-highlight` I recommend to split it out into the standard Tailwind CSS classes instead because that might be very tedious to configure in tailwind-merge (especially if you have more of them). [Read explanation](https://github.com/dcastil/tailwind-merge/blob/v1.12.0/docs/recipes.md#extracting-classes-with-tailwinds-apply)

Instead of the `text-card-highlight` class you can create a JS variable with the standard Tailwind classes in a string and reuse that everywhere. E.g.

```js
const textCardHighlightStyles = 'text-base font-medium'

// in your component
twMerge(textCardHighlightStyles, 'text-green')
```

With this in mind merging should work just fine.

Comment: I haven't used the `@apply` directive. Actually I wanted to achieve responsive fonts as provided in my website's design system. So I created classes by adding them to the tailwind config's utilities (I have updated the question with more info)

Also, moving to a JS variable will be too much of a hassle right now as the development has been going on for some time. I was using clsx before. I tried adding twMerge and got this issue.

Comment: Update: It's working now. I wasn't able to figure out how to extend the config, but your link helped me out. Thanks a ton!